# Boot Windows install environment using grub?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub

I work as a computer repair technician and we have every Windows install disk under the sun for when we need to reinstall whatever of the myriad Windows versions the customer in question may happen to have. I have consolidated many of our tools for diagnostic, virus removal, troubleshooting, etc onto a series of flash drives as well as a small Arch Linux partition for when we need to mess with stuff from outside the OS (ie: the Utilman.exe -> cmd.exe trick). I have been trying to find a way, but have yet to make any progress on making a grub menu when booting to the flash drive where I can, in addition to our troubleshooting Linux OS, boot a series of commonly used Windows installation environments.

Does anyone know of any way to boot to a Windows ISO, an extracted version of the ISO, or some specially formatted hacky pre-install environment, that will allow us to basically select an option and start up that installation?

Comment: Bit of an X-Y. TLDR: Want multiboot USB installer for Windows OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Easy2Boot with quite a bit of success. I'm not sure if the loader itself is GRUB, However I've been able to have it chain boot off into a variety of Windows and Linux environments for different tools. This DOES allow multiple flavors of Windows (Win7/8/10/x86/x64) on one device, unlike many other alternatives I've tried.

As a warning, the formatting on the site is sketchy but I have used this with success. VirusTotal if in doubt;
http://www.easy2boot.com/

Hope this is what you're looking for.